# How to mmap a file inside the linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, memory-mapping

I'm hooking some system calls using kprobes inside the linux kernel. During that, I would like to read from a file using `mmap`.

It's not possible to use system calls inside the kernel, but often there are other ways around it. (e.g. `sys_open` vs. `vfs_read`).

Is that possible and if so, how?

Comment: mmap creates a new mapping in virtual address space of a calling process, since there isnt any process since we are in kernel, it would really tricky to get it working. On the other hand why not just open in the kernel and read it (filp_open/vfs_read) ?

Comment: static int file_write(struct file* file, unsigned long long offset,
        unsigned char* data, unsigned int size)
{
 mm_segment_t oldfs;
 int ret;

 oldfs = get_fs();
 set_fs(get_ds());

 ret = vfs_write(file, data, size, &offset);

 set_fs(oldfs);
 return ret;
}

static int file_read(struct file* file, unsigned long long offset,
       unsigned char* data, unsigned int size)
{
 mm_segment_t oldfs;
 int ret;

 oldfs = get_fs();
 set_fs(get_ds());

 ret = vfs_read(file, (void __force __user *)data, size, &offset);

 set_fs(oldfs);
 return ret;
}

Comment: If I understand the inner workings of the kernel correctly, there is a process because I'm hooking the syscall. So all my code is run inside a process. Thanks for the code. `vfs_read` is indeed an alternative, but an `mmap'ed` file would work better with my existing code and I could avoid copying some memory.

Comment: just for my clarification, kernel mmap/filp_open would return you a pointer which is in kernel space, how would that avoid copying some memory ?

Comment: @PrabhakarLad Take this with a few grains of salt, I don't know that much about kernel IO. I thought that a `read` call first copies the file into the the file system cache and from there to the calling code. `mmap` however can directly map the file system cache into your process. This also has the advantage, that the system can easily page out this memory (it's already stored on the disk) if necessary.

Comment: @PrabhakarLad The real reason for this is not performance (I doubt that it matters) but it would make my code slightly cleaner.

Comment: just gave another thought (I haven’t tried it, but curious if it works !), allocate some physical memory in the kernel and then pass it on the do_mmap() and check the return value, if it succeeds, do not use the address returned, instead use the addr which you passed for do_mmap() call to access the file. the only disadvantage would be you will have to allocate large physical memory if the file is BIG.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly I am also looking for the exact same thing. Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @Psy No, it might not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, functionality of `mmap()` cannot be used from the kernel space.

While one may successfully call `do_mmap()` or similar, the function returns **user space address**, which **kernel cannot use directly**. The only correct way for access user space memory from the kernel is `copy_to_user`/`copy_from_user`. But using these functions implies *copiing*, so advantage of `mmap()` (compared to `read()`) is lost.

---

For use functionality of `read()` in the kernel, `set_fs(KERNEL_DS)` technique can be used for mask pointer to *kernel space*, passed to this function, as a pointer to *user space*, so `copy_to_user` works correctly.

But with `mmap()` one has reversed problem: he needs to work with *user space* pointer, returned from the function, as with a pointer to *kernel space*. And this cannot be done with normal means.

Attempt to dereference a pointer to user space region which hasn't mapped yet may crash the kernel. And most of `mmap()` implementations actually returns not-mapped memory, which is intended to be mapped on the first page fault.

Comment: yep, also, mmap accepts an int as file descriptor and from kernel there is not such option. The file you are going to open is returned as structs.